# Keyboard not working when using Credential parameter

Tags: powershell

When I start the powershell with Credential parameter that uses domain credentials from the domain computer, the keyboard stops working:

```
start powershell -Credential $DomainUser
```

If I start cmd keyboard works, and when I start powershell from cmd it stops again.

If I use

```
start powershell -Credential $DomainUser -ArgumentList "1+1; sleep 2"
```

I can see the commands executed normally and this is the only way I can execute them.

If I run

```
 start powershell -Credential $DomainUser -ArgumentList '-NoExit -Command "pause"'
```

I can type the letters while pause is in effect, after it finishes no typing again.

If I shift + context menu and run powershell as domain user via *Run as different user* option it works.

It happens on multiple Windows 8 and 10 OSes and Posh 4+.

Anybody knows what is going on ?

Comment: Have you tried with `-NoExit -NoProfile`?

Comment: Yeah I did do that.